# Page number problem with romannum package

Tags: packages, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I used the `romannum` package in my file, but it converted page number in roman numbers, how do I change it back?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! All page numbers? Only after a certain point? Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: `\pagenumbering{arabic}` right after `\begin{document}`. The package documentation clearly states that page numbering is changed with `\pagenumbering{roman}` but that it could be changed ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\begin{document}` or better `\AtBeginDocument{\pagenumbering}` *after* loading the `romannum` package.

The `romannum` package changes to `\pagenumbering{roman}` within its package code in the `\AtBeginDocument` - hook.

Please note that the package `romannum` has options for fine control which counters should be output with roman numbers, e.g. chapter, equation, figure etc, but interestingly, this is not possible for the `page` counter!
The `Most` option does the change using `\Roman` for `chapter` etc, the `most` is to be used for lower case roman 'figures', i.e. `\roman`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[Most]{romannum}

\AtBeginDocument{\pagenumbering{arabic}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Areedd: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!